# KD-Tree in MATLAB goes wrong on geographic dataset

Tags: matlab, geolocation, cluster-computing, implementation, kdtree

I want to implement KD-Tree in MATLAB on Geolocation dataset in order to accelerate the speed of clustering. There are functions whose name are [KDTreeSearcher](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kdtreesearcher.html) and [KD-tree](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26649-kdtree-implementation-in-matlab). The problem is that when it comes to the Geographic locations, which is contain (longitude, latitude), it gets back wrong results due to wrong calculation of the distances between instances. 
Could anyone helps me to run one of these MATLAB function for this purpose?
I don't really know what is the problems?

Comment: Before creating KD-Tree you need to translate the coordinates into a system that you think that distance measures in that system is correct.

Comment: Do not the distances change in this transformation? ..Is there any library in matlab?

Comment: There is a [mapping toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/geographic-coordinate-reference-systems.html).